# jQuery off() Before Form Submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm learning how to use jQuery and I'd like to understand what the purpose of using the off() method before submitting a form is. For example, in the following code, the form is first prevented from sending using preventDefault(), some Ajax is done and when finished, the form is finally submitted. But why do I need to use off() before submit()?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form[name="Payment"]').on('submit', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        AjaxCall();

        $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
            $('form[name="Payment"]').off('submit').submit(); // Once Ajax request are finished, submit the form.
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You will get infinite loop otherwise.

Comment: To stop subsequent clicks to trigger the submit multiple times. Essentially it turns off the submit event.

Comment: @UmairAhmed no, that is not the case here. Has nothing to do with clicks

Comment: @charlietfl yeah, my bad..

Comment: Please help me understand the reason I would get infinite loops?

Comment: By calling `submit()` you will trigger submit event handler that will run your code once again. That will call `submit` that will trigger event handler. That will call `submit` that will trigger event handler. That will call `submit` that will trigger event handler. And so on

Comment: Thank you, Yuri, I understand now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because triggering the same event would run all that same event handler code again.

The default would always be prevented, the ajax would be called ....and then the event would be triggered again and you would have an infinite loop without changing something.

Removing the event listener would make any subsequent submit use browser default process

There are other ways around this...but this answer explains what was asked

Comment: Thank you, I get it now.